# Android - I try to get data from SharePreference

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences, gson

Here is my code that I try to insert data to share Preference when I click on Item.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.popup_Favorite:
                songList = songRespones.getSongs();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(
                        SharePreferenceKey.SONG_LIST, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                String songJson = new Gson().toJson(songList.get(position));

                editor.putString(SharePreferenceKey.SONG_LIST, songJson);
                editor.apply();

                showMessage("អ្នកបានរក្សាទុក");

                break;
            case R.id.popup_cencel:
                showMessage("Cancel");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is my code that I want to get data from Share Preference

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(
            SharePreferenceKey.SONG_LIST, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String getSongJson = sharedPreferences.getString(SharePreferenceKey.SONG_LIST, "N/A");

    List<SongRespones> songList;
    if (!getSongJson.equals("N/A")) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<SongRespones>>(){}.getType();
        songList = new Gson().fromJson(getSongJson, type);
        Log.e("ppppp", songList.size() + "");
    }
}
```

But I cannot get it. It show Error below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.vichit.khmersong, PID: 20040       

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:899)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
```

**Please help me:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing a json object because `songList.get(position)` will return an object so

Change this line

```
 String songJson = new Gson().toJson(songList.get(position));
```

to this

```
 String songJson = new Gson().toJson(songList);
```

Comment: I want to data to share preference by position that I clicked.

Comment: how are you getting position in `songList.get(position)` ?

Comment: I have position when I click on recycleview and than I want to put data that I clicked into share preference.

Comment: If I write songJson = new Gson().toJson(songList); 
it put all.

Comment: yeah, if you write `songJson = new Gson().toJson(songList);` it will insert the whole list.. i thought you want to insert full list because you are retrieving the full list that's why it is showing error during retrieval because it is looking for a list but as you are inserting only an object